# Why does it show, "Wrong Password", when I am trying to start mysql from the terminal?

Tags: mysql, terminal, mysql-workbench

I was trying to start mysql from my terminal using the command "sudo start mysql", after which it asks for the password, which when I am providing, it says "wrong password". But, I know, it's the right one, as I am using the same password to connect with workbench, and it's working fine there.

Answer (score 1):

The command `sudo start mysql` is telling your linux environment to start the mysql service using `upstart`.

When you use the `sudo` command in your terminal you are telling the computer that you wish to run the `start mysql` command as `root`. It asks you for your user credentials for that computer (not your MySQL credentials).

You may have the same username created inside your MySQL database, but it may not have the same password as your Linux user.